# GetWindowRect returns different values than Spy++

Tags: winapi

I am trying to get a HWND's rectangle by the use of the Win32 `GetWindowRect` function. However, such a function does not seem to retrieve the correct values.

The window that I want the size of is a DosBox window, and I can see the correct values through Spy++. As you can see, the HWND I'm querying the size of is the correct one, but the values do not match.

[image]

I've tried also to use `DwmGetWindowAttribute`, but the values returned are the same, wrong ones.

Comment: Is your application marked as DPI aware? See [Tutorial: Writing High-DPI Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464659.aspx) and [Writing DPI-Aware Desktop and Win32 Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469266.aspx) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable Does my application (where I call GetWindowRect) need to be DPI aware or the one that I am querying? Also, if it matters, DOSBox uses SDL under the hood.

Comment: The calling application needs to be DPI-aware. Also, I don't understand, what a *"DOSBox"* is supposed to be. There is no DOS in Windows NT. The virtual DOS emulation layer is only available in Win9x. How this is related to SDL is something you will have to explain. I'm sure the Windows Console doesn't use SDL.

Comment: @IInspectable DOSBox is a DOS emulator widely used to emulate old games. I will try to make my application DPI-aware, thank you!

Comment: In case of the DOSBox application the window is just a regular window. Whether it uses SDL for rendering or the GDI doesn't make a difference with respect to querying for its size.

Comment: @IInspectable Making my application DPI-aware fixed my problem and the correct values are now returned. Please post that as an answer and I will be glad to accept it.